# « Aucune nouvelle » ou « aucune nouvelles » ?

Tags: négation

Quelle est la différence de signification entre les phrases ci-dessous ?

> Je n'ai reçu aucune nouvelle d'elle.
>
> Je n'ai reçu aucune nouvelles d'elle.

Answer (score 8):

La deuxième phrase doit s'écrire:

> Je n'ai reçu **aucunes** nouvelles d'elle.

Il n'y a pas de différence de signification, mais dans le deuxième cas, on considère que nouvelles est toujours au pluriel dans l'expression :

> recevoir des nouvelles.

tandis que dans le premier cas, on considère valide l'expression :

> recevoir une nouvelle.

Avec « pas », je préfère le pluriel, comme dans l'expression figée:

> [Pas de nouvelles, bonnes nouvelles](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/nouvelle).

Le pluriel est majoritaire dans la littérature:

[image]

en revanche avec « aucune », le singulier est largement majoritaire :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Je suis d'accord avec la réponse de Feelew: en anglais, on utilise le pluriel avec un nombre de zéro, par exemple "no excuses". En français, à l'inverse, on utilise le singulier, donc la phrase correcte ici est:

> Je n'ai reçu aucune nouvelle d'elle.

Answer (score 0):

En anglais, la marque du pluriel avec un nombre de zéro est commune, mais en français, elle est bien plus rare. Je n’ai eu vent que des noms ne possédant aucun singulier pour la requérir, par exemple “*aucuns frais*”.

Le terme “*nouvelles*” a une acception strictement plurielle dans le sens de renseignements à propos de quelque chose ou quelqu’un dont on n’a plus entendu parler depuis un temps. Ce pourrait être le sens de la phrase dont vous présentez deux versions. Cependant, la marque du pluriel devrait s’étendre aussi à *aucune*

> Je n’ai r**e**çu aucune**s** nouvelles d’elle.

Une autre acception de “*nouvelle*” qui peut cette fois être singulière (et ne peut donc prendre la marque du pluriel en négation) est celle de l’annonce d’un développement récent relié à un événement connu. Si, par exemple, *elle* est entrée à l’hôpital pour accoucher, n’avoir reçu aucune nouvelle d’elle pourrait être ne pas savoir si elle a déjà accouché, si ce fut une fille ou un garçon, si tout s’est bien déroulé, etc.

> Je n’ai r**e**çu aucune nouvelle d’elle.

Dans ce même dernier sens, *elle* pourrait être une journaliste, dont le patron se soucie de la productivité en ce sens qu’elle déniche peu de nouvelles. Par exemple, depuis une semaine, dit-il, “*Je n’ai r**e**çu aucune nouvelle d’elle.*” Mais ce pourrait être un peu tiré par les cheveux, car excessivement spécifique, et peu applicable hors de ce genre de contexte particulier.

Comment: C'est à peine que je vois "aucun(e)s" en effet, pour la raison que vous venez de donner : "aucun(e)" précède un singulier. C'est pour ça que je le traduis par "not one" lorsque mes étudiants souhaitent avoir la traduction "littérale".

Comment: @LukeSawczak Would you say "Not ones trousers"? ;-)

Comment: @jlliagre "What do you mean I cut up those pants with those scissors? I never cut up a single pant with a single scissor!" But no, you're right, one has to make exceptions. :p Liaison-triggering cases like *aucuns arrhes* also show that plural *aucun* isn't just a writing convention but a live one too. I guess the determining factor is indeed whether *nouvelle* is allowed to appear in the singular. (I feel like *aucun* is so eager to take a singular, though, that even a noun that generally prefers to be plural is likely to appear in the singular if any singular-looking form is attested!)

Comment: Why is anyone talking about English? English has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: Indeed Luke, a lot of people could feel the way you do. Actually, even for words with only plural forms attested, it is a common feeling in French that the negation would need to be singular, from the deeply rooted French understanding of nothingness and its obvious relation to the unplural world (nothing being less than singular and plural being more than singular). Also, now that more and more institutions and printers are operating with few or no professional correctors, uncommon subtleties like these have more chances to be overlooked, and might make incorrect forms appear more often.

Comment: Lambie, j’avais supposé que quelqu’un qui écrivait _réçu_ n’avait pas le français comme langue maternelle. Comme beaucoup ici semblent avoir l’anglais comme langue maternelle, j’ai sauté sur l’occasion de mettre le doigt sur une différence entre les deux langues qui m’avait frappé lorsque je l’avais rencontrée (la surprise étant le pluriel de l’anglais dans mon cas). C’est tout. Ça me coûte un vote en bas, mais ce n’est pas grave.